# Pl/SQL json list loop

Tags: json, plsql

How can I retrieve content from below json by using pl/sql json from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pljson/?

{"errors":["Invalid weight","Invalid pallet spots"]}

I want to get text like this 1. Invalid weight, 2. Invalid pallet spots.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite simple:

```
DECLARE
    obj json := json();
    arr json_list := json_list();
BEGIN
    obj := json('{"errors":["Invalid weight","Invalid pallet spots"]}');
    arr := json_list(obj.get('errors'));

    dbms_output.put_line(arr.get(1).get_string());
    dbms_output.put_line(arr.get(2).get_string());
END;
/
```

You might also want to have a look at my own (performance optimized) version of a json library for PL/SQL @ https://github.com/doberkofler/PLSQL-JSON

Comment: Hello @materialdreams, your work its useful 2 me, thanks a lot!